# How to create VSCode task creating a file without BOM

Tags: json, powershell, visual-studio-code, byte-order-mark

I need to create a JSON file when launching an Angular e2e test, basing on gopass key. Unfortunately I'm getting JSON encoded as UTF-8 with BOM.

I created task in tasks.json launched by one of launch configuration, tried to configure it without success. Problem is caused by PowerShell, which by default write files with BOM characters.
I was trying to change task type to process (run with key and output file as args too), but then I got problem with not selecting proper gopass key or with running command.
I cannot make slight changes in my test code, so I need to set it by tasks.json/launch.json.

My current task configuration:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "Get data",
    "command": "gopass \"somekey\" > \"myFile.json\""
},
```

I want to get JSON file without BOM character

Comment: As an aside: `>` in Windows PowerShell doesn't just create a BOM, it uses _UTF-16LE_ encoding ("Unicode"), not UTF-8.

Comment: @mklement0 Thanks, but I think, there's no simpler solution for that than you suggested, or is there some way to get rid of  `>` in favor of something else?

Comment: These are the basic choices: (a) Go with PowerShell Core, as in my answer (which isn't simple enough for you). (b) Modify your command to use .NET directly to write the file, as shown in Theo's answer and now also in context at the top of mine. (c) **If** you know that your data *never* contains non-ASCII-range characters, you can get away with using `Set-Content`, as in js2010's answer: use `| Set-Content \"myFile.json\"` instead of `> \"myFile.json\"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Theo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57441675/45375) shows you how to make Visual Studio Code's default shell on Windows, *Windows PowerShell*, create *BOM-les*s UTF-8 files, which, unfortunately, is quite cumbersome, because it isn't supported with standard operators and cmdlets.

The shortest formulation in your case would be to replace:

```
"command": "gopass \"somekey\" > \"myFile.json\""
```

with:

```
"command": "[IO.File]::WriteAllLines(\"$pwd\myFile.json\", (gopass \"somekey\"))"
```

---

**To retain the convenience of defining your `tasks.json` tasks as unmodified PowerShell command strings** that can use `>`, while also producing BOM-less UTF-8 output, you can **make your task use PowerShell *Core* (v6+) as the shell instead, because PowerShell Core's file-output cmdlets and operators consistently *default* to BOM-less UTF8**:

**Prerequisite:** Make sure that [PowerShell *Core*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell#get-powershell) is installed.
The **bottom section** shows how to perform **automated on-demand installation**.

Note: *Eventually*, PowerShell *Core* will come preinstalled on Windows, alongside the legacy Windows PowerShell edition, but this (a) won't happen for a while and (b) no specific time frame is known.

---

- **If you're OK with *globally* substituting PowerShell Core for Windows PowerShell** - which then requires no change to your task definition:

Note: This means that the *integrated terminal* as well as all `"shell"`-type tasks in `tasks.json` will use PowerShell *Core*.

Open `setting.json` (from the command palette, select `> Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`) and add the following property:

```
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "pwsh.exe"
```

<sup>Note: If `pwsh.exe` is not in your system's `PATH`, specify the *full* path in the `"executable"` property; you can obtain it by opening a PowerShell Core window and executing `(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path`.</sup>

---

- **If you want to substitute PowerShell Core for Windows PowerShell *task-individually***:

Add an `"option"` object to your task-definition JSON to make it use PowerShell Core's CLI instead of Windows PowerShell's:

```
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "Get data",
    "command": "gopass \"somekey\" > \"myFile.json\""
    "options": {
      "shell": {
         "executable": "pwsh.exe",
         "args": [ "-noprofile", "-command" ]
      }
    }
}
```

---

#### Using automated *on-demand* installation of PowerShell Core on Windows:

Since it is easy to perform an automated user-level installation of PowerShell Core, you can fully automate the whole process as follows:

- Define a new `EnsurePsCoreInstalled` task that checks for the presence of PowerShell Core and installs it, if needed.

  - It will be installed to `$env:LOCALAPPDATA\powershell`.
  - Of course, when the on-demand installation occurs (once per machine), there will be a noticeable delay.
  - **Important**: After the one-time installation **Visual Studio Code won't find `pwsh.exe` right away**, so you need to either:

    - Log off from Windows and back on (or reboot), then restart Visual Studio Code
    - Quit Visual Studio Code, open a *new* PowerShell window and restart it from there (simply run `code`).
    - This requirement is unfortunate, but Visual Studio Code as of v1.37 doesn't pick up in-session environment changes; if you'd like to see that changed, vote for the [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47816).

```
{
    "label": "EnsurePsCoreInstalled",
    "type": "process",
    "command": "powershell.exe",
    "args": [
        "-noprofile",
        "-command",
        "if (gcm -ea ignore pwsh) { exit 0 }; Write-Verbose -vb 'Installing PowerShell Core...'; iex \"& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-powershell.ps1) }\"; $dir = $env:LocalAppData + '\\Microsoft\\PowerShell'; $userPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User') -split ';' -ne ''; if ($dir -notin $userPath) { [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', ($userPath + $dir) -join ';', 'User') }; $env:Path += ';' + $dir; if (gcm -ea ignore pwsh) { Throw 'PowerShell Core was just installed on demand. To make it usable, log off and on again or reboot, or restart Visual Studio Code from a new PowerShell window (run `code`).' } else { Throw 'Installation of PowerShell Core FAILED.' }"
    ],
    "problemMatcher": []
}
```

- To make your `Get Data` task execute task `EnsurePsCoreInstalled` first, add the following property to it:

  - `"dependsOn": "EnsurePsCoreInstalled"`
  - Note: Doing so will slow down your task, because task `EnsurePsCoreInstalled` will then be invoked first *every time*. While it quickly returns if it finds that PowerShell Core is already installed, Windows PowerShell itself, which runs the task, has a noticeable startup cost.

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that as of PowerShell version 6 both `Set-Content` and `Out-File` support **UTF8NoBOM** encoding.

If your version is less than 6.0, you can use the either code below to save the json string as UTF8 without the BOM:

```
$json = @"
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "Get data",
    "command": "gopass \"somekey\" > \"myFile.json\""
}
"@
```

Use the [UTF8Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.utf8encoding.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_UTF8Encoding__ctor_System_Boolean_) object with the `encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier` parameter set to $false

```
$Utf8NoBom = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $false
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText('D:\launch.json', $json, $Utf8NoBom)
```

OR

Use a [StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) object which by default outputs UTF8 without BOM

```
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter 'D:\launch.json'
$json | Out-String -Stream | ForEach-Object { $sw.Write($_) }
$sw.Dispose()
```

Comment: That's helpful in general, but note that the JSON in the question is not itself to be written to a file; it is a Visual Studio Code _task definition_ that contains a PowerShell command line to execute by Visual Studio Code, via its default shell, which is Windows PowerShell. The OP's desire is to have the command embedded in the task, `gopass "somekey" > "myFile.json"`, produce BOM-less UTF-8.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `System.IO.File` methods too default to BOM-less UTF-8, so your 1st command can be simplified to: `[IO.File]::WriteAllText('D:\launch.json', $json)` - no need to construct and pass an encoding object.

Answer (score 0):

If you use set-content, there won't be a bom.  The default in PS 5 is "ansi".

Or maybe you're talking about vscode itself?  The default encoding for saving is utf8 no bom.

Comment: While the question is a bit ambiguous, it's fair to assume that BOM-less _UTF-8_ is desired, because that is JSON's default encoding in the absence of a BOM: "_JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is UTF-8._" (from section 3 of [RFC 4627](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt)). Now, you may _get away with_ using the active ANSI encoding (or even `-Encoding ASCII`) if the input text happens to contain characters in the 7-bit ASCII range only, but that assumption should be clearly stated.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but generally my wish was to obtain result of task "Get data" in proper _json_ format, that can be used in further operation.

Comment: I'm using `"gopass \"somekey\" > \"myFile.json\""`, but @mklement0 solution works for me.